# Use separate source to populate bound Datagridview Combobox dropdown list?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

[Here's a screenshot of the Employee Schedule form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fPIF.jpg)I have a c# windows forms Employee Scheduling app form with a datagridview bound to my schedule table on it.  The grid has a combobox field called EmpID that links to my employee table and displays "EmployeeName" from the Employee table (Schedule.EmpID = Employee.EmpID).  The EmpID field has the following settings:

```
Datasource=employeeBindingSource;
Displaymember=FullName;
ValueMember=EmpID;
```

I want to populate the datagridview combobox EmpID dropdown with a separate listing of Available Employees names and associated EmpID's for the user to select from and populate the Schedule table EmpID field with.  Is this possible?

Schedule Table:
EmpID, Date, Position, .....

Employee Table:
EmpID, FullName, Address, .....

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what problem are you having doing that?

Comment: The problem is that I can't figure out how to populate the list for the combobox with separate values from the source that it's bound to.  I'd like to give the user Displaynames as Employee Name and DisplayValues as EmpID from a separate listing of Available Employees.  If what I'm looking for won't work, Is there a way to tie a separate combobox to float over the datagrid control that I can show and hide as they enter data?  It would have to look like it's part of the grid though.

Comment: It is difficult to visualize what you are describing. If you want the combo box to contain the “Employee Names” then loop through the list/data source of the names and add them to the combo box. Again, it is difficult to visualize what you want this combo box to do. Is it used as a filter? It would help if you could show with a picture what you want to achieve and what you want to happen if the combo box value is changed.

Comment: I have a complete example application, [check it out on Github](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid)

Comment: I just added the image of the form.  The field in question is the Employee Name Field dropdown in the upper grid.  I'd like to be able to control the items presented to the user (along with key values to use in the background) in the dropdown, while still maintaining the current functionality of the field within the grid.

Comment: Currently, what do the combo boxes in the upper grid contain? How did the current names get in there to begin with? I am guessing that each combo box MAY contain different names?

Comment: If all you need is to allow the user to pick a field value from a list then that is very common functionality. Check out the link I gave you. I that does not exemplify what you are trying to do then you need to try to re-state your requirements in different terms.

Comment: I'll try to explain it better:  The dropdown for the Employee Name field in the upper grid contains the EmpID (key value) of my employee and is stored in the Schedule table (which is displayed in the upper grid).  The names that you see displayed are from combobox Displaymember property since I have that combo bound to my Employee table (and using EmpID as the valuemember).  All that works great.  Now I'd like to have the drop down listing contain ONLY the names from the bottom grid, and then have the selection put the matching EmpID into the valuemember field of the uppergrid.

Comment: Another way to say it is in the image, if you click on the dropdown on the upper grid, it currently has all the names from the bound source.  Instead, I want that list to come from the bottom grid and show only the employees that are available to be scheduled.  I'd like it to contain just the 3 items:  "Bridget Fransky", "Toblerone Fisher", and "Troy Derma".

Comment: A combo box column must have the same data source for all rows but you can fake it by applying a filter to its data source in the EditingControlShowing event. It's possible you might be able to find an example I wrote on the MSDN forums years ago that does this but I don't remember the implementation now.

Comment: Thanks Crowcoder, I'll do some digging and see what I can find.  I like the implementation, now I just need to see if I can make it work!

Comment: After reviewing the requirements in your question, I must say that there is some important info missing. Example, you state you want the combo boxes in the grid at the top to contain only the names from the bottom grid, when the user clicks on the combo box. As crowcoder stated, this is not difficult using a filter on the combo boxes data source. However, what do you want to happen AFTER the user selects a name from the bottom grid?

Comment: If the user changes a currently “unassigned” name to one of the names from the bottom grid… do you want to remove that name from the bottom grid? Moreover, what happens when there are no more names in the bottom grid? Should the combo box be empty? In addition, what do you want to happen if a currently selected name is already assigned and the user changes it? Do you want to add the changed name back into the available employees’ grid? If you do not, then you will not be able to select that name again.

Comment: Your relatively simple requirement to have the top grids combo box’s contain only the names from the bottom grid is not difficult to implement. However, I am not sure if you have completely thought this through, and if you have, then please supply this important information. Your simple question, is not difficult to implement, the other consequences I mentioned above… is a completely different story.

Comment: JohnG, your thoughtful questions show that you understand my challenges!  I don't think the filter is going to work.  The reason is because that bottom grid is actually a list of ALL available employees for that day, but all scheduled employee's rows are hidden in the current view. The user can select to see all employees (see the radio buttons), and my thought would be that the dropdown would coincide with the user's choice.  For that reason, I'll need to programatically add and remove items from the listing using a ForEach loop on the bottom grid based on what they've chosen.

Comment: JohnG, for the other functionality of the grid, my thought was that if they assign someone, the lower grid would mark them as scheduled, and depending on their selected radio button choice, they would either see them in the lower grid or not, as well as the dropdown.  I do think having the dropdown match the lower grid would help clear things up for the user.  For them to move someone, they would have to unassign them from their currently assigned position and then reassign them to the new position.  I'm completely open to other ways to implement this though!  Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Your last comment clears some things up. Is the bottom grid’s data source “filtered” or is it filled with ONLY the unscheduled employees? I am guessing it has a “filter” (or it should) since there is the radio button to display all the employees. I am guessing because I do not see a column for “Scheduled or Not scheduled” in the bottom grid. How are you “filtering/determining” which names should be displayed in the bottom “unscheduled” grid? Is there possibly a bool column “Scheduled/NotScheduled”? Can you show the code that “filters” the data source for the bottom grid (if it exists)?

Comment: Have you considered, creating a small “add unscheduled employee to schedule” “Form”? This approach will separate the logic from the previous “Worker Schedule” UI. Everything for adding an employee to the schedule could be encapsulated in this small form. I am guessing this may make things easier for you and should be user friendly.

Comment: If the grids `CellDoubleClick` event is wired up, a check can be made to see if the “Employee Name” combo box column was double-clicked, if it is… then show dialog (to lock the user) to the “add employee to schedule” form. With this approach I am guessing you could possibly eliminate the combo boxes altogether. Just a thought.